# How do I keep an updated TextView (via SharedPreferences) on the UI?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've got this TextView (txtCounter), which updates itself every time I run a service. Said process runs smoothly, but whenever I close the application and open it up again, the TextView doesn't show the actual variable, only after I once again run the service.

I know I need to do something in the onCreate (or onResume?) method, something along the lines of receiving the updated TextView from the method which updates it (in my case, it's "UpdateUI") but I don't know what.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView txtCounter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button startApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startApp);
    final EditText timer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertTimer);

    assert startApp != null;
    startApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Countdown, Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class);
            assert timer != null;
            intent.putExtra("timer", timer.getText().toString());
            startService(intent);

            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);

            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MainService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
        }
    });
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { updateUI(intent); }
};

private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
    txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int counter = pref.getInt("counter", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("counter", ++counter);
    editor.apply();

    assert txtCounter != null;
    txtCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try { unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver); } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {}

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I just noticed, you no longer need to pass an `intent` to `updateUI()` since we aren't reading anything from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the following method in `onResume()`:

```
// read counter variable and update the textview
private void updateTextView() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int counter = pref.getInt("counter", 0);
    setCounterTV(counter);
}


// Update the textview with a counter value
private void setCounterTV(int counter) {
    txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);
    assert txtCounter != null;
    txtCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
}


// Method to be called by your service
private void updateUI() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int counter = pref.getInt("counter", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("counter", ++counter);
    editor.apply();

    setCounterTV(counter);
}
```

Comment: How is this method different from the OP's `updateUI()` method?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  `updateUI` also updates the `counter` which he wants to call repeatedly exclusively from one of his services

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Use a method name which differentiates this more from the original `updateUI()` method. 2. Refactor the original `updateUI()` method to call this one to reduce code duplication.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice true, give me a second to make the edits

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @VladPintea I refactored the code a bit...check the update above

Comment: @Shaishav Much more organized, indeed. Thank you, again ^.^